# Get an Object from a TreeView node in C#

Tags: c#, treeview

I'm writing an AutoCAD Plug-in that shows all the entities as Nodes in a TreeView. I want to be able to get the object from the Node to be able to work with programmatically. This is my code for when a node is clicked:

```
private void treeView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = node;
        /*Entity selectedEntity = node.getObject() as Entity; Pseudo-code, need to know how to do this*/
    }
```

Comment: There is `TreeNode.Tag` for storing an arbitrary object ref if that's what your looking for.

Comment: That worked, put it as an answer for points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeNode` has a [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property that's designed to allow you to associate an object with a Node.